# Contract deployment on Polygon mainnet being stuck

Tags: gas, gas-price, polygon, pending-transactions, hardhat-deploy

So I've been trying to deploy the simplest contract on Polygon mainnet for hours now with no luck. The transaction is stuck on pending. I tried with many different contracts and I tried changing the provider I'm using (Alchemy free tier https provider).

I also tried to increase the maxPriorityFeePerGas as well as maxFeePerGas.
This is one of the transactions: https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x9ea8aebad73b073e167efd2a8ab81f998e2759ff98fa8b5d20cb640849380053

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract Test {
    // struct details for staking
    uint public value;

    // Initialisation section

    function set(uint _value) public  {
        value = _value;
    }

}
```

And this is the code I'm using for deployment (with hardhat)

```
async function deployContract() {
    
    const ContractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("Test");

    const contract = await ContractFactory.deploy({
        gasPrice: BigInt(1000 * 10 ** 9),
    });

    await contract.deployed();

    console.log(`Contract deployed to ${contract.address}`);
}


// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises
deployContract().then(() => 
    console.log("Done")
)
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Possible cause: 1/ Pending transactions, 2/ Not enough balance to pay the fee, 3/ Congested network.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not specify the gasLimit, it would be determined by hardhat automatically from the rpc node.

Eg.

```
 const contract = await ContractFactory.deploy();
```

Comment: I already tried that before trying to edit it manually